# Why are ranger classification forest probability predictions exactly 0.5 when using low `sample.fraction` on particular data?

Tags: r, classification, probability, random-forest, r-ranger

**Context**

Using the `ranger` package in R, I am training a probability forest on a binary response.

**Problem Summary**

For particular combinations of data size and `sample.fraction`, all predicted probability values are precisely 0.5.

Small tweaks to either of these move the predictions away from precisely 0.5 to hovering near 0.5.

**Question**

Why?

**Code**

Raw class frequencies are 5/65 and 60/65. For demo purposes, use noise covariate only.

```
response <- c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 60))
df <- data.frame(resp=as.factor(response), noise=rnorm(65))
```

Using the `sample.fraction` argument to approximate class balance in the sampling of observations, we train the model and observe the out-of-bag predicted values. All are exactly 0.5 with no variation.

```
r <- ranger::ranger(formula=resp~noise, 
                    probability=TRUE, replace=TRUE,
                    data=df,
                    # Lowering sample.fraction below 5/65 also results in predictions of 0.5. 
                    # Raising it to 6/65 changes the results.
                    sample.fraction = c(5/65, 5/65), 
                    num.trees=150,
                    importance='impurity',
                    keep.inbag = TRUE)
r$predictions
```

Making small tweaks to the problem setup moves the predicted values away from precisely ambiguous (even if they are still practically ambiguous). Let's say I instead use data of twice the size, but the same raw class proportions and `sample.fraction` argument.

```
# rf on something exactly as rare as 5/65, but more observations
df2 <- data.frame(resp=as.factor(rep(response, 2)),
                 noise=rnorm(130))
rf_df2 <- ranger::ranger(formula=resp~noise, 
                      probability=TRUE, replace=TRUE,
                      data=df2,
                      sample.fraction = c(5/65, 5/65), 
                      num.trees=150,
                      importance='impurity',
                      keep.inbag = TRUE)
rf_df2$predictions
```